# Provider type could not be represented as a .NET type OracleTypeException

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, oracle, data-access

So I have an application that is writing to an oracle database, then another that is reading the data from the same database.

When I get to the line `Dim msgTime As TimeSpan = reader.GetTimeSpan(2)`, I get an exception (see below).

The Oracle Documentation says that `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` (which is how I'm storing the data in the DB) can be converted to timespan (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B28089_01/OracleDataReaderClass.htm#i1006518))

Does anyone know what causes this exception, and how to avoid it?

Thanks.

---

Exception:

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleTypeException
Provider type could not be represented as a .NET type
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.TimeSpanConv.GetTimeSpan(OpoITLValCtx* pValCtx, OracleDbType oraType)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetTimeSpan(Int32 i)
   at MyProgram.pollDatabase(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
```

Write to DB code:

```
Dim oCommand As New OracleCommand("INSERT INTO LOGTABLE(PK, MID,MDATE,MTIME,STATUS,SEVERITY,ORIGQ,MESSAGE) VALUES (:pk, :msgid, :msgdate, :msgtime, :status, :severity, :message)")

oCommand.Parameters.Add("pk", OracleDbType.Varchar2, Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 12), ParameterDirection.Input)
oCommand.Parameters.Add("msgid", OracleDbType.Varchar2, message.MessageID, ParameterDirection.Input)
oCommand.Parameters.Add("msgdate", OracleDbType.Date, putDateSQL, ParameterDirection.Input)
oCommand.Parameters.Add("msgtime", OracleDbType.IntervalDS, putTimeSQL, ParameterDirection.Input)
oCommand.Parameters.Add("status", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "NEW", ParameterDirection.Input)
oCommand.Parameters.Add("severity", OracleDbType.Varchar2, messageSeverity, ParameterDirection.Input)
oCommand.Parameters.Add("message", OracleDbType.Clob, clob, ParameterDirection.Input)
```

Read from DB Code:

```
Dim conn As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection(oradb)
Dim oCommand As New OracleCommand("SELECT MID,MDATE,MTIME,STATUS,SEVERITY, ORIGQ, MESSAGE FROM LOGTABLE")
oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
oCommand.Connection = conn
oCommand.Connection.Open()
Dim reader As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader()

If reader.HasRows Then

    While reader.Read()
        Try
            Dim messageID As String = reader.GetString(0)
            Dim msgDate As Date = reader.GetDateTime(1)
            If Not reader.IsDBNull(2) Then
                Dim msgTime As TimeSpan = reader.GetTimeSpan(2)
            End If
            Dim msgStatus As String = reader.GetString(3)
            Dim msgSeverity As String = reader.GetString(4)
            Dim msgOrigin As String = reader.GetString(5)
            Dim msgContent As String = reader.GetString(6)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End While

End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use `Dim msgTimeInterval As Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleIntervalDS = reader.GetOracleIntervalDS(2)` instead of `Dim msgTime As TimeSpan = reader.GetTimeSpan(2)`